# Instead of downvotes of academic discuss why not encourage contest response allowing fair and valid explanations?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, reference-request

Concepts and proofs are contestable in Scientific discuss and academics but the practice is usually supported by references (usually peer review, and known authorities in the discipline). I do notice some unfair downvotes just because someone is angry, perhaps just for reputation, defense of own response/answer, unfriendly habit, racism or just not yet exposed to similar line of presentation of work or facts of graduate academics, and advancement in knowledge on the topic.
Though we can flag, It will be "super fair" that reasons should be supplied to downvotes and ( much better) response to contest  and put right Academic concepts and methodology (and using verifiable references) for sake of contribution to knowledge rather than unproductive reputation. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct; Downvotes are not always fair nor valid.  But it's also true that not all Upvotes are valid.

Comment: The choice of tags seems rather strange to me. I do not see that this has to do with ([meta-tag:mathoverflow]). But the tag ([meta-tag:down-votes]) seems the most natural tag given the topic - yet that one was not used.

Comment: You can find several related discussions here on meta. To list just a few: [Why do people think downvotes need explanation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29205), [Downvoting for no stated reason is abusive](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3153), [In praise of silence](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9404), etc.

Comment: How can this be ensured; that a particular suspected unfair downvote is fairly addressed. Reputation of voters, indeed lend credence to their votes, and which atimes is contestable. Hope support listed guidelines for addressing issues like this, revoke or confirm a downvote.

Comment: Yeah, you were right there, @Martin Sleziak. Have made the corrections to the tags. Thanks

Comment: Downvotes (either with or without explanation) are often unfair and/or invalid.  So are upvotes.  As Martin Sleziak points out, this has been discussed to death in the past here on meta.  I am not sure what this topic adds to the conversation...

Comment: "I do notice some unfair downvotes just because someone is angry, perhaps just for reputation, defense of own response/answer, unfriendly habit, racism or just not yet exposed to similar line of presentation of work or facts of graduate academics, and advancement in knowledge on the topic." If the downvotes are made without explanation, then you have no way of knowing whether they were made for any of the reasons you have listed. If you have **evidence** that a downvote was cast out of anger, or racism, or other unfair motivation, please flag the question for moderator attention.

Comment: @OP I looked at your sole question, and I observed two things. 1. It has 1 downvote. That's not a lot. 2. It certainly is worthy of downvotes. You presented a PSQ, which is strictly against the guides provided on this site for good questions.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/785985/gerry-myerson

Comment: @Don Thousand, I don't think I have gone against any rule, and you are a bit hard there. Am not the only victim, new users can't be abreast of all discuss but get educated and directed via prognosis like this. And, thanks for your alternative view, everyone's opinion always seems right to the person, except for deliberate sincerity.

Answer (score -12):

NOTE PLS: as brought to my notice, this question's formal structural construct which relates to " unfair downvotes and what to do" already  has answers here: ( [Downvoting for no stated reason is abusive](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/downvoting-for-no-stated-reason-is-abusive))" and here ([Why do people think downvotes need explanation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29205/why-do-people-think-downvotes-need-explanation) )" . Thanks.

Comment: This should be added as an edit to your question, or a comment below your question.